# Adding Seconds on to my Timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

what i am doing is on my level the timer counts down from 50 to 0 using Time.deltaTime this works great. now on the PlayerControl Script when i pickup a coin i want the timer to Add on 3 seconds. My code is below.

//this is PlayerControl when i pick up PlusOrb Object.

```
public class PlayerCTRL : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text timerText;
    public TimerCount timerScript;
    public Image DamagedOverlay;
    public float speed;
    public Text CountText;
    private int count;
    public GameObject TakeDamage;
    public Text scoreText;
    public TEMPLE_score scoreScript;
    public TEMPLE_GlobalSettings globalSettings;

    void Start()
    {
        CountText.text = CoinCounter.ToString();
        playerLife = 3;
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        playerAS = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        timerScript = GetComponent<TimerCount>();
        damaged = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PlusOrb"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
            //score
            scoreScript.myscore += 2;
            scoreText.text = scoreScript.myscore.ToString();
            //timer
            timerScript.timer + 3f;// this is the problem i am having
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CoinCount", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CoinCount") + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

//This is the Timer Script.

```
public class TimerCount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text TimeText;
    public float timer1 = 50;
    float SceneTimer = 0;
    TEMPLE_GlobalSettings globalSettings;
    public Sprite lives0;
    public GameObject Gore;
    public PlayerCTRL PlayerController;
    int ouch;


    void Start()
    {
        timer1 = 50;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        this.GetComponent<Text>().text = timer1.ToString("F0");
        timer1 -= Time.deltaTime;

        print(timer1);
        if (timer1 < 1)
        {
            timer1 = 0;
            PlayerController.playerLife = 0;
            SceneTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            //if (SceneTimer > 2)
            //{
            //SceneManager.LoadScene("TEMPLE");
            //}
        }
    }

    void GameOver()
    {
        GameObject thisGore = Instantiate(Gore, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        thisGore.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        GameObject.Find("Lives").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = lives0;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
timerScript.timer + 3;// this is the problem i am having
```

with

```
timerScript.timer += 3f;
```

Or

```
timerScript.timer = timerScript.timer + 3f;
```

This is a [basic](https://www.dotnetperls.com/increment) C# stuff. You should learn C# before working with Unity. There are many of tutorials out there.

**EDIT**:

With the updated script in your question, there is no variable named `timer` in your `TimerCount` script. A similar variable name in your `TimerCount` script is named `timer1`. You should either rename it to `timer` or `timerScript.timer1 += 3f;`.

At the end of the day, this means that you need to learn basic C#. Please don't take this as an insult. It necessary to understand basic C# or you will be asking more similar questions like this one. You are accessing a variable is is not declared.

Comment: yer that's what i tried i thought it would work but it still doesn't work. thanks man for your answer.

Comment: What doesn't work? Don't just say say it doesn't work....Tell us what exactly doesn't work

Comment: i tried all of them and  now its the timer that displays the red line timerScript.timer = timerScript.timer + 3f; or timerScript.timer += 3f;

Comment: timer has red underline

Comment: How about this? Edit your question and post complete `PlayerControl` script. Then also post your complete `Timer` script. I want to see what problem you are having.

Comment: ok so it is working but when i puck up the object in game game stoppes and says null reference exeption on this line timerScript.timer1 += 3f;

Comment: when i pickup the orb it stoped the game with an error null refernece on timerScript.timer1 += 3f; line.

Comment: That's because your `TimerCount` script is not attached to the GameObject your `PlayerCTRL` script is attached to.You have to find the GameObject `TimerCount` script is attached to then get that component from it.   Replace `timerScript = GetComponent<TimerCount>();` **with** `timerScript = GameObject.Find("GameObjectTimerCountIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<TimerCount>();`. Make sure to change `GameObjectTimerCountIsAttachedTo` to the name of GameObject that has `TimerCount` attached to it.